cs50 week 6 dna incorrectly identifies sequence
I have been stuck on this for hours. When I run it it says this
dna.py exists
:) correctly identifies sequences/1.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/2.txt
:( correctly identifies sequences/3.txt
    expected "No match\n", not "Bob\n"
:) correctly identifies sequences/4.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/5.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/6.txt
:( correctly identifies sequences/7.txt
    expected "Ron\n", not "Petunia\n"
:) correctly identifies sequences/8.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/9.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/10.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/11.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/12.txt
:( correctly identifies sequences/13.txt
    expected "No match\n", not "Petunia\n"
:) correctly identifies sequences/14.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/15.txt
:( correctly identifies sequences/16.txt
    expected "No match\n", not "Albus\n"
:) correctly identifies sequences/17.txt
:( correctly identifies sequences/18.txt
    expected "No match\n", not "Lavender\n"
:) correctly identifies sequences/19.txt
:) correctly identifies sequences/20.txt

Here is the code:
def main():

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna,py data.csv sequence.txt")
        sys.exit(1)

    database = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            database.append(row)

    with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as file:
        dna_sequence = file.read()

    subsequence = list(database[0].keys())[1:]

    result = {}
    for subsequences in subsequence:
        result[subsequences] = longest_match(dna_sequence, subsequences)

    for person in database:
        match = 0
        for subsequence in subsequences:
            if int(person[subsequences]) == result[subsequences]:
                match += 1

            if match == len(subsequences):
                print(person["name"])
                return

    print("No Match")
    return


A detailed explanation on where I when wrong.

The issue seems to be with the matching of subsequences in your code.
The problem was that the match variable was being reset to 0 for each subsequence, rather than for each person in the database. Also, the check for a match (if match == len(subsequence)) should be outside the inner loop.
def main():

    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna,py data.csv sequence.txt")
        sys.exit(1)

    database = []
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        for row in reader:
            database.append(row)

    with open(sys.argv[2], 'r') as file:
        dna_sequence = file.read()

    subsequence = list(database[0].keys())[1:]

    result = {}
    for subsequences in subsequence:
        result[subsequences] = longest_match(dna_sequence, subsequences)

    for person in database:
        match = 0
        for subsequence in subsequence:  # Corrected here
            if int(person[subsequence]) == result[subsequence]:
                match += 1

            if match == len(subsequence):  # Corrected here
                print(person["name"])
                return

    print("No Match")
    return

This way, it checks if all subsequences match after checking all subsequences for a person, not after checking each subsequence.
